# Declaring object out of scope

Tags: javascript, function, scope, declaration, userscripts

I have this function:

```
function createElement() {
    var element1 = document.createElement("div");
    element1.id = "el1";
    //...
}
```

the problem is that when I create another function, let say `editElement()`, I cannot access `element1` from within the new function as it's out of scope.

I could declare `element1` outside of those functions, but then the problem is that `element1` gets declared all the time. But I may need to create the element only in the fraction of the cases, only when a user presses a button and `creadeElement()` gets called. I want to save system resources and call `document.createElement("div")` only when I really need it, but I also need to access it from within multiple functions. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: It is bad practice to dynamically add to dom like this, it is not good design

Comment: @theBigChalk Can you elaborate? DOM manipulation is frequently done, including adding elements.

Comment: @theBigChalk: What are you talking about? Why would that be bad practice??

Comment: It's a userscript. I don't have access to html source and userscript/javascript is the only way to add elements that were not there in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply assign your new element to window so it available in global scope

```
function createElement() {
    window.element1 = document.createElement("div"); //Meke new element global.
    element1.id = "el1";
}

function useElement() {
    //now you can use element1 directly. as it is inside the global scope.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, do something like this:

```
var element1 = null;
function createElement() {
    element1 = document.createElement("div");
    element1.id = "el1";
    //...
}

function useElement() {
    if(!element1)createElement()
    //...
}
```

This will make the element available outside the createElement function, but won't create the element until it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object:

```
var elementHandler = {
    createElement: function() {
        this.element1 = document.createElement("div");
        this.element1.id = "el1";
        // ...
    },
    editElement: function() {
        // Use this.element1 here...
    }
};
```

You call `createElement` and `editElement` like this:

```
elementHandler.createElement();
elementHandler.editElement();
```

(Or you might just call them `create` and `edit` as there's no need to repeat the word "element" all over the place...)

If hooking them up to an event, be sure you call them such that `elementHandler` is `this` within the call:

```
// Using an anonymous function
someElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
    elementHandler.createElement();
}, false);

// Or using ES5's `bind`
someElement.addEventListener("click", elementHandler.createElement.bind(elementHandler), false);

// *NOT* like this:
someElement.addEventListener("click", elementHandler.createElement, false);
```